# Is there a way to create named ranges for spreadsheet exports?

Tags: export, spreadsheets

I am trying to figure out whether I can tell Mathematica to name ranges for data that I am exporting? I want to use this data in CPLEX, which unfortunately doesn't allow the use of the R1C1 notation, so using named ranges is the only way I can think of to make sure that I process the data automatically.

Thank you!
- a Mathematica beginner